# Python Replace values in list with dict

Tags: python, loops

I have 2 variables I am trying to manipulate the data. I have a variable with a list that has 2 items.

```
row = [['Toyyota', 'Cammry', '3000'], ['Foord', 'Muustang', '6000']]
```

And a dictionary that has submissions

```
submission = {
    'extracted1_1': 'Toyota', 'extracted1_2': 'Camry', 'extracted1_3': '1000', 
    'extracted2_1': 'Ford', 'extracted2_2': 'Mustang', 'extracted2_3': '5000', 
    'reportDate': '2022-06-01T08:30', 'reportOwner': 'John Smith'}
```

extracted1_1 would match up with the first value in the first item from row. extracted1_2 would be the 2nd value in the 1st item, and extracted2_1 would be the 1st value in the 2nd item and so on. I'm trying to update row with the corresponding submission and having a hard time getting it to work properly.

Here's what I have currently:

```
iter_bit = iter((submission.values()))

for bit in row:
    i = 0
    for bits in bit:
        bit[i] = next(iter_bit)
        i += 1
```

While this somewhat works, i'm looking for a more efficient way to do this by looping through the submission rather than the row. Is there an easier or more efficient way by looping through the submission to overwrite the corresponding value in row?

Comment: You are not explicit about this, it the *reason* `extracted1_1` matches the first item in the first row because the key end in `1_1`? You're code doesn't seem to look at the keys, but is depending on order (which is not a great idea with dicts).

Comment: You can use `for i, bits in enumerate(bit):` instead of incrementing `i` yourself.

Comment: @Mark the submissions come in labeled as such to match the column and row, so it would be extractedColumn_Row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through `submission`, and check if the key is in the format `extractedX_Y`. If it does, use those as the indexes into `row` and assign the value there.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^extracted(\d+)_(\d+)$')

for key, value in submissions.items():
    m = regex.search(key)
    if m:
        x = int(m.group(1))
        y = int(m.group(2))
        row[x-1][y-1] = value
```

Comment: When I run this it is showing m = None Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: I had a typo, I wrote `$` where I meant `^`.

Comment: That did the trick! Appreciate this, as this allows for more flexibility than my initial attempt.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to convert the portion of the keys after `"extracted"` to indices into `row`. To do this, first slice out the portion you don't need (i.e. `"extracted"`), and then split what remains by `_`. Then, convert each of these strings to integers, and subtract 1 because in python indices are zero-based.

```
for key, value in submission.items():
    # e.g. key = 'extracted1_1', value = 'Toyota'
    if not key.startswith("extracted"):
        continue

    indices = [int(i) - 1 for i in key[9:].split("_")]
    # e.g. indices = [0, 0]

    # Set the value
    row[indices[0]][indices[1]] = value
```

Now you have your modified `row`:

```
[['Toyota', 'Camry', '1000'], ['Ford', 'Mustang', '5000']]
```

Answer (score -1):

No clue if its faster but its a 2-liner hahaha

```
  for n, val in zip(range(len(row) * 3), submission.values()):
     row[n//3][n%3] = val
```

that said, i would probably do something safer in a work environment, like parsing the key for its index.